# How to store the time at which an action is performed in java

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to java and selenium. So my requirement is when a button is clicked, i want to record the time at which that button click happened to an element and compare the value in that element(in H:mm format) with some value.

I have to  record the time at which the below element is clicked:

```
@Test(priority = 7)
    public void selectRightNow() {
        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-send-associates-page/ion-content/div[2]/div/div/ion-row[4]/ion-col[1]/div[1]")));
        actions.click();
        actions.build().perform();
    }
```

And compare here instead of the current time i have used below:

```
Assert.assertTrue(element.contains((new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a")
                .format(new java.util.Date()).toString() + "  to  Clock-out")));
```

Comment: Why don't use `java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()`, later you can convert it to the desired format ?

Comment: Or LocalDateTime.now()

Answer (score 0):

To get instant time you can use the below line..

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
```

(available from Java 8)